# how to restart a foreach loop in js;

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.thumb').each(function(i){ 
                if(i>= 4){
                    $(this).addClass('col-' + (i));
                }{
            $(this).addClass('col-' + (i));

                }
```

and i want result like [image]

what i do to add this class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the modulo operator:

```
$('.thumb').each(function(i){ 
  $(this).addClass('cold-' + (i % 4));
}
```